# Running my compiled java application on my android phone?

Tags: java, android, jar, emulation

I am fairly new to java programming but I'm currently learning it in school as I am a first year IT student. Anyway, I made myself a "tool" for a certain game IRL (not rly important what it is). Anyway, I've managed to compile it to a .jar file which runns fine on my pc but as it's basically a program that helps you keep scores while playing a card game IRL I'd much rather have it working on my phone instead because bringing the computer to the table to have besides you when you play is not really that optimal imo... 
So bottom line my question is: Is there a way for me to run my program on my android phone and if so how? I've tried some emulators but they've either not run it or just given me errors for some reason. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem like you haven't tried to build GUIs in Java yet.
You need to do your research about Android Studio, Android and GUI design. Also, here is some free courses from [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/courses/android) for android

Comment: Yeah no haven't had time for that yet. I was just thinking if there's some easy well functioning emulator that would make it work instantly? Not really planning on making it for playstore anyway so don't mind a bit of hazzle. The hole thing is using JOptionPane